# Every $2$-coloring of $K_n$ contains a hamiltonian ...

Tags: graph-theory

> Every $2$-coloring of $K_n$ contains a hamiltonian cycle that is made out of two monochromatic paths.

If there is a monochromatic hamiltonian cycle then we are done. Elseway I thought about using [Dirac's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path#Bondy.E2.80.93Chv.C3.A1tal_theorem) somehow (I know that there is in both monochromatic induced subgraphs there is a vertex with degree higher than $n/2$).

- $K_n$ is the [complete graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) on $n$ vertices.
- A [Hamiltonian cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) is a cycle that visits each vertex exactly once.
- A $2$-coloring of the graph is a partition of the set of edges in two sets (for example the "blue" edges and the "red" edges).

Comment: Ok , if there is a monochromatic hamiltonian cycle then we are done.
Elseway I though about using Dirac's theorem somehow (I know that there is in both monochromatic induced subgraphs there is a vertex with degree higher than $n/2$)

Comment: Cute problem.  No need to use Dirac's theorem or any other big result;  instead, induction seems to be the way to go.

Comment: @TylerSeacrest Sorry but I can't see how to use induction here...
I tried throwing a general vertex with no success :P

Comment: Hmm, I'll try writing up a proof and see if my induction idea works ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Choose any vertex $v \in K_n$.  Then $K_n \setminus v$ is a 2-colored copy of $K_{n-1}$, and thus by induction contains a Hamiltonian cycle that is the union of a red path and a blue path.  Let $u$ be  a vertex where these two paths meet, and let $r$ be $u$'s neighbor along the red path, and $b$ be $u$'s neighbor along the blue path.

Suppose $uv$ is colored blue.  Then throw away $ur$ and instead use $uv$ and $vr$ in your Hamiltonian cycle (it does not matter what color $vr$ is).  If $uv$ is colored red, then throw away $ub$ and use $uv$ and $vb$ in your Hamiltonian cycle.  Either way, you've extended your Hamiltonian cycle to include $v$ and it is still the union of a blue and red path.

I've ignored the case where the Hamiltonian cycle in $K_{n-1}$ is monochromatic, but it is trivial to extend the cycle to $v$ in this case.

Comment: Yeah I had a mistake , it really does't matter what vb and vr are , thanks =D